# Link_to doesn't change params[:controller]

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I changed my stylesheet link tag to load based on controller like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller], :media => "all" %>
```

Things work out fine if I load the page in my browser for example `localhost:3000/users/sign_up` but when I visit the page via link such as this

```
<%= link_to "User-Signin", new_user_registrations_path, class: "page-scroll" %>
```

it doesn't load the stylesheet for that controller. Any idea why? Thanks.

Application.css

```
/*
 *
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_self
 */
```

Config/initializers/assets.rb

```
%w( landing_pages products users/registrations).each do |controller|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js", "#{controller}.css"]
end
```

Comment: Can you show code for application.css?

Comment: Yup..there you go. Thanks.

Comment: ok this looks okay, can you please also share config/initializers/assets.rb code where you tell which controller assets to compile